Please give feedback that a tag does not exist when a user tries to add a non-existent tag to the watched tag list on the Settings page
When trying to add a tag to the watched tag list from the settings page, it is possible to type in a non-existent tag into the autocomplete input box and then press "Watch tag".
The non-existent tag then disappears and no feedback information about the success or failure of adding the tag is given to the user.
By the way, non-existent tags cannot be added here to the watched tag list, which is currently as expected.

Of course, the user can scroll down the list of tags to check whether the tag has or has not been added. However, no clear feedback is given to the user that the non-existent tag does not exist on the site immediately after pressing "Watch tag".
However, if we try to add a non-existent tag to the Watched Tags box in the right sidebar on the Questions page, feedback is clearly given when a red popup appears informing us that the non-existent tag does not exist on the site:

My request therefore is:
Please display a red popup also on the Tag watching tab of the settings page when trying to add a non-existent tag to inform the user that the tag does not exist on the site. For example:

Please also add a similar feedback message for the Ignored tags input box on the settings page too.
